# How is memory on the stack identified if it doesn't have pointers?

Tags: c++, c

Correct me if I'm wrong but pointers are identifiers (an ID) given to each bit of memory. If the memory on the heap has pointers it can be identified which gives the code ability to delete, modify or even change it's size. The confusion comes when I've read a book saying stack doesn't have pointers.

I've been reading the book 'Head First C', and it was talking about pointers. Was it simply refering to pointers just as an example? Or does the memory on the stack have some kind of pointer to memory?

If not, how is it identified? The confusion or contradiction between web posts and books have really confused me on a subject I am only just understanding. Can anyone clear this up?

Comment: It sounds like you misunderstood whatever the book was saying. The claim you're attributing to the book makes no sense.

Comment: A pointer is just a variable that holds the address to something else as its value. Where you normally think of a variable holding an immediate values, such as `int a = 5;`, a pointer would simply hold the address where `5` is stored, e.g. `int *b = &a;`. In other words `b` *points* to where the value of `a` is stored (e.g. `b` *points* to `a`).

Comment: Each memory chunk has an address. A pointer is just a store whose contained value is a memory address. You can have a pointer containing any address you want, but referring to that address may not be possible (some are forbidden to use in some way).

Comment: So both stack AND heap have pointers to their values or pointers to their memory slots, or if `char*` pointers to the first element of that array? Or is it only heap.

Comment: A pointer is a pointer is a pointer --- it can hold any address -- whether that points to an address on the stack or whether it points to allocated memory -- makes no difference. It's just a pointer. (which is just a normal variable that holds the address to something else) A pointer must be initialized and store a valid address to something. When a pointer is declared it is **uninitialized** until it is assigned a value. (bad things happen when people attempt to use uninitialized pointers....)

Comment: Every object has a size and int he stack it's all, wait for it, stacked one atop the other. You push your way up, and pop your way down. No ids are necessary, you just need to know how much stuff to put on and then how much to pull off when it goes out of scope. The compiler takes care of it for you.

Comment: It might help to post the exact text from the book

Comment: And as another bit to foster your understanding, the stack is typically being used to allocate space for variables declared in a subroutine.  A pointer to a stack memory address will no longer be valid after a subroutine returns because that address can and will be re-used.

Comment: In my experience, the ”Head first” books are pretty awful.

Comment: Maybe the thing you have not realised is that there is an *implicit* stack pointer created by the compiler, not you, every time you call a function. All stack variables are referenced via offsets from this pointer you can't see.

Comment: I would assume that the book wants to tell you that you can access memory on the stack without using pointers. You can simply use `int var;` and lateron `var = 123;` in your function and don't need to bother with pointers. Memory on the heap cannot be accessed without explicitely using pointers.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: You're thinking of x86. It's not universal. SPARC had a register file.

Comment: @MSalters if your C program takes the address of a local, the SPARC compiler has to put that local somewhere addressable

Comment: @Caleth: Actually, you might be surprised at how good compilers can be. For instance, if you just `printf` the address, you might find that the compiler never bothers to spill the register. The "AS-IF" rule is pretty powerful.

Comment: @MSalters Ok, "takes and *uses in some non-trivial way* the address of a local".

Answer (score 5):

Every memory location has an *address*.  There is nothing like the idea you suggest that stack memory does not have addresses.

A pointer value is the address of a memory location, and a pointer variable is a variable that can store a pointer value.

Comment: In C pretty much anything has an address. The exception are temporary values and objects declared as `register`.

Answer (score 0):

Data in the stack is referenced by an offset from the stack/base pointer.

When your program is executed, a chunk of memory is allocated by the OS for its purposes. The stack will then be used by your program to store data that is required for normal execution. Note that this chunk of memory may not be sequential in the physical memory but a virtual memory space mapped by the OS.

When a variable is defined locally in a function, the compiler will generate code that reads a chunk of data in the stack that is used to represent your variable. Care is taken by the compiler to ensure multiple variables will not occupy the same space. Note that a optimising compiler can still use the same space for several variables if previous definitions are deemed as useless within the execution flow (Not to be confused with lifetime validity of a variable in C++).

This process however, is only applicable when you know exactly how much memory you need at compile time, meaning the compiler will be able to generate an offset for each named variable defined in your program. This means that there is no need to explicitly read a memory location, aka dereferencing of pointers. **However, this does not mean that the variable itself does not reside in a memory location and does not have an address that can reference it.**

When writing programs that require dynamic memory allocation, you will have to explicitly tell the OS to allocate more memory to your program. Since this memory location is dynamic, the address will not be known at compile time, meaning data access can only be done via dereferencing memory locations. In this case, it will be the additional chunk of memory allocated by the OS.

Last but not least, compilers can and will always try generate code that stores variables in registers, hence referencing a variable can be very different depending on the code generated.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the stack is contiguous in virtual memory space either. It can be a linked list, in which case the data is not referenced by an offset. Remember, a function can't directly access stack variables from its caller, so there's no need for those to be located at an offset to its own.

Comment: Maybe I am not* understanding you correctly, can you elaborate on how a stack can be a linked list?